# Objective C++ Crash on C++ String Array Append

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, append, objective-c++

The following Objective C++ routine, if I run it enough in XCode 7.1 on OS X 10.11, eventually crashes on the string append. The debugger shows me that it stops every time at the number 23 (trying to append the number 23). I imagine this has to do with memory allocation. What am I doing wrong?

The debugger opens the string class and jams on the return statement below. In the other debugger window it says (lldb), whatever that means.

```cpp
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::append(const basic_string& __str)
{
    return append(__str.data(), __str.size());
}
```

Here's my code I'm running that seems to cause the crash if I run the routine enough times. (This was only present during monkey testing, where I clicked on my Settings menu in my Objective C/C++ application enough times that it triggered the following function enough times to crash.)

```cpp
std::string Minutes[] = {};
std::string s = "";
for (int i = 1; i<= 59; i++) {
    s = std::to_string(i);
    if (s.length() < 2) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    s = ":" + s;
    Minutes->append(s);
}
```

This might be a plain old C++ question, perhaps not an Objective C++ question. Or, perhaps this is an Apple bug?

Note that I ran an experiment with the following change, and it **never crashed** after 3 attempts of 100 times:

```cpp
std::string Minutes[] = {};
std::string s = "";
for (int i = 1; i<= 59; i++) {
    //s = std::to_string(i);
    /*
    if (s.length() < 2) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    s = ":" + s;
    */
    //[Minutes->append(s);
    Minutes->append("01");
}
```

Also, the following patch of code also runs 3 times, up to 100 times, without an issue:

```cpp
const std::string Days[] = {"Su","M","T","W","Th","F","Sa"};
std::string Hours[] = {};
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    Hours->append(std::to_string(i));
}
```

Comment: `std::string Minutes[] = {};` That isn't valid C++. But if it were, what would you expect it to do?

Comment: Initialize an empty array so that I can append items to it? I'm kind of green with C++.

Comment: `Minutes->append(s)` does not append to the array, it instead attempts to call `append` on the first `std::string` in the array - even when there isn't one.

Comment: OK, you've declared a zero-size array, so there isn't much you can do with it, even if your compiler lets the code pass as an extension. Also, there isn't such a thing as an empty array in C++. Arrays have a fixed size, and contain a fixed number of elements. There are standard library types which model dynamic arrays, which can be empty. For example, `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @jaunchopanza So, I'm doing it wrong, it seems. Unlike my Days string array, which seems to work, then I need Minutes to be a vector and then append strings to that vector, right? If so, then I need to read up on what vectors are in C++.

Comment: Also, the answer from @Steephen below works with the `{""}` as far as preventing the crash, but it also showed me that I'm not building a string array as I thought, but a single string, which was an undesired approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to keep null string in Minutes, do as follows

```
std::string Minutes[] = {""};
```

Then `Minutes->append(s);`will append `s` to first null string inside the Minutes[] array.

UPdate:

First you have to create a dynamic array( std::vector) of string, in case if you don't know the size of the array as follows and use index to access the string from std::vector.

```
// implies that you used #include <string> and #include <vector>
std::vector<std::string> Minutes;
Minutes.push_back(s)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this seems like bad advice. In the comments he said he expected to append to the array, not to the first array element...

Comment: I can say this, however, this change did prevent the program from crashing during monkey testing! Yay! However, it also showed me that when I thought I was appending minutes, I was actually appending to a string, not an array of string. How do I append to an array of string like I did with Days successfully (although I hard-coded that one)?

Comment: This is still appending to a string *in* the array, when he wants to append a string *to* the array. i.e. `std::vector::push_back`...

Comment: This works. I also had to learn to add `#import <vector>`, not just `#import <string>`.

Comment: @Volomike `#include`